# How do I make a TCP connection between LabVIEW server and Python client where (data) angles from Python are to be transferred to LabVIEW?

Tags: python, tcp, labview

How do I make a TCP connection between LabVIEW server and Python client where (data) angles from Python are to be transferred to LabVIEW?

Comment: Hi Eugene, I can see you have a problem from the number of questions you asked but please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Posting multiple roughly the same questions won't get them answered quicker, but tend to discourage people form answering them.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your "how do I do this" question. First, start from the basics. Do not start with a more complicated program that has some error as you showed in [robotic wrist mimicking - Kinect as a Sensor(Python Coded) to a labview Simulation using TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44126398/robotic-wrist-mimicking-kinect-as-a-sensorpython-coded-to-a-labview-simulati).

**With almost any LabVIEW problem, first check the LabVIEW examples in the Example Finder.** Start with the LabVIEW "Simple Data Client.vi" that can be found in the LabVIEW examples, accessible via Help->LabVIEW Examples-> (search on tcp/ip server). For reference here also the code snippet:

[image]

From the Python side, just send a simple number or list of numbers. If this is working then you know you have set up your server and client correctly. Until that is working, you should not worry about more complicated code. After the communication working then you can expand your code.

In case it is not working, ask a very specific question about the part that is not working. Include any error codes and describe what you did, what the responses of the program were, and what responses you expected.

Comment: Good day D.J. Klomp ..thanks for the information  , I found it but I chose the UDP instead of TCP .. (Simple UDP.lvproj) ..I have already sent a string from Python to the Simple UDP receiver and it was successful .The moment that I encounter errors is when I execute and arrrange the robotic vi block diagram with the UDP receiver diagram...I have to transfer a number (angle in degree) from a python to LabVIEW for the robot to simulate ..

Comment: Do you get a reproducible error and what is it? If not I think your best bet is to reconstruct your vi until you find the error. Forward reconstruction: start with your working UDP project and slowly add your other functions until errors appear. Than you should know which exact part of the program creates the problem. Backward reconstruction: take your non-working project and slowly take out functions until it works without error. Good luck with it, sometimes communication errors are very hard to debug.